# Google Cloud SQL crashes when running INSERT queries

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, innodb, google-cloud-sql

For about two weeks we’ve been experiencing problems with Cloud SQL. After issuing an INSERT statement with 2 000 000 records to the database, SQL instance “crashes”. Developers console shows our SQL instance is Runnable but the database is unreachable and throws “[Err] 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 0” when trying to connect. Also, every time it crashes the procedures that have been altered are reverted to their previous state (probably latest backup) but actual data is not affected. We’re using InnoDB for the engine.

When the SQL instance becomes unresponsive we are also unable to see a list of databases via web console (under Databases) which indicates the problem is neither with our network nor our credentials.

We have observed this issue when running INSERT INTO .. SELECT statement from within a stored procedure. It inserts into an empty table on which there are primary and secondary indexes. We have tried removing secondary indexes but the issue is still there.

We’ve noticed that there’s a massive increase in read operations and read/write InnoDB pages. 
[image: graph read op cloud monitoring]

[image: graph innodb read write cloud monitoring]

It’s also a bit peculiar that these metrics differ in Cloud Monitoring and Overview (Storage->SQL in the Developers console). However, both graphs show an increase.

[image: graph read overview]

[image: graph innodb write overview]

We have tried enabling logging to a TABLE but after the “crash” we are getting this error message:
“Error Code: 145. Table './mysql/general_log' is marked as crashed and should be repaired”

We have used Cloud SQL for one year and this is never happened before.
Current SQL instance spec: 4GB RAM, over 60% of 250GB used.

Has anyone experienced similar problems recently? We’ve only started having them two weeks ago.

What variables / parameters should we be looking at to optimize the queries?

Is it possible that the recovery after the crash is using the latest backup to restore the procedures but leave the data untouched?

Comment: Sorry to hear your Cloud SQL instance became unresponsive. For this question, it is necessary to exchange specific information about your instance. Will you send an email to `cloud-sql@google.com` with your instance name and a link to this post?

Once your issue is sorted, we can post generalized findings to help other Stack Overflow users.

Note: Brett H. asked me to re-post this as a comment.

Comment: Turn off the "general log".